# Fetch data and fill redux store on server

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I'm using react with react-redux and react-router and I'm trying to define a static method in my components that is used to fetch the necessary data for that component from the server. The actions are async and I make use of the redux-thunk middleware. Calling the actions individually works fine, but I don't want to have to manually define which actions need to be called when, and instead would like to just loop through the components on the server and call the static method as necessary.

I have tried using something like this to loop through all the components, but I can not get it to work. I suspect it is because my components are nested.

```
  return Promise.all(
    components
      .reduce((previous, current) => {
        return (current && current.fetchData || [])
          .concat((current && current.WrappedComponent ? current.WrappedComponent.fetchData : []) || [])
          .concat(previous);
      }, [])
      .map(fetchData => dispatch(fetchData(params)))
  );
```

Something else that might be a potential issue is that some of my routes render multiple components like this:

```
<Route
  components={{ foo: Foo, bar: Bar }}
/>
```

How should I go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: I think you are looking for something like https://facebook.github.io/relay/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Redux-Connect](https://github.com/makeomatic/redux-connect/blob/master/README.MD) (this is a maintained fork of the original redux-async-connect).

The difference here is that, instead of having a static method, you wrap the component and define the promise fetching data from within there instead. It's nice in that way because it transfers the responsibility of fetching the data to outside of the component itself.

For what you are after in particular, see the `loadOnServer` function. It goes through all the components that you intend to render, finds the relevant HOCs and runs them. Ideally your redux store is now looking exactly how you want it to render correctly first time. You can then continue with the render in the callback.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for something like https://facebook.github.io/relay/

If you can't use that, you could just dispatch the necessary actions on your serverside store. If your components need a ton of data you obviously don't want to do that...

An option would be to define a `fetchInitialData()` function on the server side which dispatches all the actions.

On the other hand, you should keep the amount of data you are going to fetch on the serverside low. You may lose the rendering speed you gained from serverside rendering, because react can't render without ALL the data being there.

Comment: This doesn't sound right. I don't want to use Relay and I don't believe its a requirement for what I want to do. And secondly, I don't want to have to define what data each components needs on the server. When the user visits `/foo` they might need fundamentally different data than if they visited `/bar`, and vice versa. And fetching them both, always, sounds terrible.

Comment: Are you using express/node.js for your server? You can define a middleware (not talking about redux middleware here) to do the data fetching for specific routes. Or just do it in your (serverside) router.